# Number of invalid nearest neighbours in a regular n-dimensional cubic grid

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a regular finite grid of $D$ dimensions, with $l$ points per dimension. Within the bulk of the grid, a point has $2D$ neighbours. For a point on an edge of the grid, however, some of these neighbours do not exist. For example, in the $1$-dimensional case, there are 2 points with 1 invalid neighbour, totalling 2 invalid neighbours.

I am trying to work out how many invalid neighbours there are in a grid of arbitrary $D$ and $l$, and also how many points there are with $n_{invalid}$ neighbours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about a $D$ dimensional [hypercube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube) with a lattice inside it.  The Wikipedia page has a section about the number of each piece of the hypercube, points, edges, faces, etc.  For your question about invalid neighbors, note that you hypercube has $l^D$ lattice points in it.  A hypercube of the same dimension but with $l+2$ points in each dimension will include your hypercube, the invalid points, and the outside corners.

If we position one corner of the hypercube at the origin the other is at $(l,l,l,\ldots)$ with $D$ coordinates.  A point will have one invalid neighbor for each coordinate that is either $0$ or $l$ because adding or subtracting $1$ in that coordinate will take you outside the original hypercube.

For a point to have $k$ invalid neighbors, you choose $k$ of the $D$ coordinates to be on the edge, choose whether the coordinate is $0$ or $l$, and require that all the other coordinates be in the range $[1,l-1]$, so there are ${D \choose k}2^k(l-1)^{D-k}$ points with $k$ invalid neighbors.

Comment: What about edges of faces etc.? [they can be next to various numbers of invalid points.] (+1)

Comment: @coffeemath:  redone.  I hope OP looks back. because it was badly wrong.

Comment: Ross-- That looks right now, thought along similar lines...